# CMSampleBufferRef to Audio Video for RTMP streaming

Tags: ios, streaming, rtmp

I am using iOS `libRTMP` to connect to an RTMP server. Now my problem is, how can I send the audio and video to an RTMP server? I've seen that `CMSampleBufferRef` is used for processing and sent to the server. The data is being processed with some flash video like metadata.

I tried *VideoCore* but it fails with the server I am using(*Evostream*) but works with other servers. Medialibs works but I need an open source option.

How do we convert `CMSampleBufferRef` to a format that RTMP understands?